# display three.js scene across multiple screens

Tags: three.js

is it possible to use threejs to display the same scene in different browser windows? or even in Fullscreen across multiple displays?

i know it is possible to render the same scene from multiple views into one window, so the breaking point is if it is possible to pass the render context to another browser window.

i have not found any examples for this use case and a rough first try fails:
https://codepen.io/tp_up/pen/vYBqLEq?page=1

```
  secondWindow = window.open();
  secondWindow.document.body.innerHTML = '<canvas id="scene"></canvas>';
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas :secondWindow.document.getElementById('scene')});
```

the reason for the question is that we want to know if a web app that renders to multiple screens is feasible or if we have to make a native application for that use case.
so a yes / no answer with a reason would be enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This example](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_multiple_canvases_grid) in the official list of examples shows exactly that use case. You just need to add some options (like a query parameter) to decide which view to draw and base display off the time. [This example](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_multiple_canvases_circle) also shows that use case assuming the monitors are in a circle instead of a grid. And [this example](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_multiple_canvases_complex) shows that use case as well assuming the monitors are of different sizes.

The first and the last example use [`PerspectiveCamera.setViewOffset`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/cameras/PerspectiveCamera.setViewOffset) to choose which portion of a larger image to draw.

From [the docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/cameras/PerspectiveCamera.setViewOffset):

> `.setViewOffset ( fullWidth : Float, fullHeight : Float, x : Float, y : Float, width : Float, height : Float ) : null`
>
> fullWidth — full width of multiview setup
>   fullHeight — full height of multiview setup
>   x — horizontal offset of subcamera
>   y — vertical offset of subcamera
>   width — width of subcamera
>   height — height of subcamera
>
> Sets an offset in a larger frustum. **This is useful for multi-window or multi-monitor/multi-machine setups.
>
> For example, if you have 3x2 monitors and each monitor is 1920x1080 and the monitors are in grid like this:
>
> ```
> +---+---+---+
> | A | B | C |
> +---+---+---+
> | D | E | F |
> +---+---+---+
> ```
>
> then for each monitor you would call it like this:
>
> ```
> var w = 1920;
> var h = 1080;
> var fullWidth = w * 3;
> var fullHeight = h * 2;
>
> // A
> camera.setViewOffset( fullWidth, fullHeight, w * 0, h * 0, w, h );
> // B
> camera.setViewOffset( fullWidth, fullHeight, w * 1, h * 0, w, h );
> // C
> camera.setViewOffset( fullWidth, fullHeight, w * 2, h * 0, w, h );
> // D
> camera.setViewOffset( fullWidth, fullHeight, w * 0, h * 1, w, h );
> // E
> camera.setViewOffset( fullWidth, fullHeight, w * 1, h * 1, w, h );
> // F
> camera.setViewOffset( fullWidth, fullHeight, w * 2, h * 1, w, h );
> ```
>
> Note there is no reason monitors have to be the same size or in a grid.

As for different browser windows you'll need to come up with a way for them to communicate with each other. If all the animation is based on the time then you just need to keep the time in sync (or use the system clock as in `time = Date.now()`) to keep things in sync. otherwise you can pass messages across windows using postMessage.

[Here's an example](http://greggman.github.io/doodles/syncThreeJS/syncThreeJS.html). Open multiple windows and they should stay in sync.

[image]

Comment: thank you. the last example is exactly what i was looking for. since we would have to synchronize a lot of data, i will have a deeper look into the code example, to see if this solution is feasible for us.

Comment: the example is using http://docs.happyfuntimes.net/ for synchronizing the windows. i will try to use post-messages instead, but this seems feasible

Comment: The example above linked above is not using happyfuntimes as all the windows are on the same machine. As for syncing data the example syncs no data except field of view and number of balls. All other objects position themselves based on a clock. As long as that clock is in sync things will appear at the correct place. This is how the sample above works. happyfuntimes provides a cross machine synced clock. That's also how [the WebGL Aquarium](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=64TcBiqmVko) works.

Comment: the example description https://github.com/greggman/hft-syncThreeJS mentions that the fov and number settings are also synchronized via happyfuntimes. we will try to find a solution which does not require always-online and would work as offline webaap. post-messages https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage seem to be the way to go.

Comment: Yes, use postMessage or whatever. My confusion is I didn't link to happyfuntimes anywhere and the syncThreeJS I linked to on my answer doesn't use happyfuntimes so I'm confused why you brought it up at all.