# Distributing high resolution rendering on server of many computers

Tags: three.js, webgl, distributed-computing

I have a grid of monitors (12*2=24 monitors) running as one big monitor (Big wall-sized display).

I built a visualization with three.js with more than 10 000 000 data points and 12690 x 3840 resolution. So with this visualization the GPU’s full power is used and the interaction with the visualization is getting slow.

I would like to distribute the rendering on 12 computers through a server to get better performance, be able to add more data points and interact smoothly.

How can I implement that?

Comment: How many cores? Depending on data processing interdependence, the machine may already have grunt to handle the data processing needs (webWorkers). For rendering that depends on the GPU load. If it is flat out rendering pixels, workers will not help. If however the GPU has  idle time waiting for data then workers MAY help a little. But with JS you are flying no hands and blind, could run smooth and then randomly crawl. You need to go native (C++) from janky browser app to slick and fast native app. BTW 12690 is strange, I think you meant 12960

Comment: Can we use the GPUs of workers ? 
BTW , yeah it was 12960=1080*12

Comment: Yes you can use `OffscreenCanvas` API to access `WebGL` in workers. However with only one GPU and many cores you must be very careful. Syncing GPU calls across threads is tricky Only one worker at a time can access the GPU and as JS is blocking a worker waiting for a draw call will deny other workers access. Best is one thread to handle the GPU off loading non render processing to threads.

Answer (score 4):

There's an examples [here](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_multiple_canvases_circle.html) and [here](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_multiple_canvases_grid.html).

And this answer: [display three.js scene across multiple screens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58170126/display-three-js-scene-across-multiple-screens/58171968#58171968)

There's also [this non-three.js example](https://webglsamples.org/aquarium/README.html) but it does show a solution
and [this three.js one that runs across machines](https://github.com/greggman/hft-syncthreejs)

Basically you setup a server to relay websocket messages across the machines. That might sound scary but with node.js it's not that much code (I'm sure other languages have simple solutions too).

Each machine needs to know which portion of the scene to display and needs to have the same scene (or the portion of the scene that machine will display). The animations on the machines should be tied directly to a clock. As a start you can use `Date.now()`. Once it's working you can use the websockets to keep the clock synchronized across the machines. Otherwise if there are interactive camera controls or other settings, as long as they are global you can broadcast them to all machines over websockets.

If there is more interaction then you can pass the inputs or other data between machines but ideally you need to make it so not much needs to be synced and so the simulation is deterministic so that given the same state (time + settings) each machine will generate the same display state.

Comment: The visualization is already synchonized. I don't want to distribute the visualization but just the rendering. The 12690 x 3840 resolution runs on one single computer but I want to distribute the rendering over other GPUs computers as part of the network to improve performance. Did you get my concern ?

Comment: I don't understand your distinction between visualization and rendering. The examples posted above, for example the aquarium is drawing 8640x1920. It would run the same speed (60fps) on 108000x1920 (100 machines, 100 monitors) because each machine is only rendering 1920x1080

Comment: The difference is in my case:
I have only one browser running on Windows machine with 12690 x 3840 resolution (all 24 displays are running one operating Windows system). How to use the GPU's of  other computers of a distant server to improve the performance of our visualization ?  
In the examples that you mentionned, each display is running under one computer and one browser which make 24 browsers on 24 displays. BUT we have ONLY OONE browser running on Windows with 12690 x 3840.

Comment: I'm still not understanding your question. If you only care about speeding up the simulation then your question has absolutely nothing to do with 24 monitors and your tags of mutiple-montitors and high-resolution are irrelevant to your question. If so please remove those tags and everything about multiple monitors as they irrelevant to distributing computation.

Comment: Yeah the only concern to speed up the simulation using a computers network. High resolution is the reason why I want to use a network of machines.